# Errors upgrading DSX-Desktop 1.2.0 to 1.2.2

Tags: dsx-desktop

## datascienceexperience,#DSX, #ibm-data-catalog, #ibm-data-refinery, #DSX-Desktop

I have DSX-Desktop 1.2.0 installed on my Lenovo Thinkpad T440p under RHEL 7.4 Linux.  Main screen indicates "Update Available".

When I select "Update for Linux", it fails with unable to update /usr/bin which is owned by "root" owner.  I can switch to "root" via Sudo on command line, but don't know how to invoke the update by CLI.

Here is the DSX-Desktop.log file:

```
[2018-02-26 12:07:26:0074] [debug] Initialized logger!
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0533] [info] Version: 1.2.0
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0533] [info] Operating System: Linux
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0535] [info] InitialPage() container
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0646] [info] Mounting Preferences
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0685] [info] Render ToolsModal for 
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0686] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0699] [info] Mounting UpdaterContainer
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0705] [info] checking for updates....
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0706] [info] Calling check for updates...
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0706] [info] Checking for app updates...
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0727] [info] Checking for image updates...
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0734] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0735] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0989] [info] Checking docker and images on application start up.
[2018-02-26 12:07:28:0995] [info] The Projects are dsx-samples,defaultProject
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0138] [info] Found version 1.2.2 at https://github.com/IBMDataScience/DSx-Desktop/releases/download/1.2.2/ibm-dsx-desktop.AppImage
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0257] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0260] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0261] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0262] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0310] [info] Getting update information from updates.json
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0324] [info] Notebook updates not available...
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0324] [info] dsxJSON is [object Object]
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0325] [info] DSX updates not available...
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0325] [info] util: emit update-not-available for image
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0325] [info] controller: emit update-available
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0334] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0336] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0336] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0346] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0353] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0353] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0356] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0356] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0356] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:29:0357] [info] CONTAINER: Need to update app
[2018-02-26 12:07:39:0366] [info] dockerConfirm: true
[2018-02-26 12:07:39:0366] [info] Docker is up and running.
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0501] [info] Calling download updates...
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0501] [info] Downloading Updates...
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0503] [info] Downloading updates from https://github.com/IBMDataScience/DSx-Desktop/releases/download/1.2.2/ibm-dsx-desktop.AppImage
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0509] [warn] Cannot write to the directory /usr/bin
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0512] [info] controller: emit update-downloading
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0517] [info] Container:Update downloading
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0521] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0522] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0522] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0537] [error] Cannot write to the directory /usr/bin
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0548] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0549] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0549] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0551] [info] Set state visibleModal error
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0553] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0554] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0554] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0621] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0622] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0622] [info] false
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0626] [info] The updateAvailable is true
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0630] [info] Render UpdaterModal
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0630] [info] false
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, an app update just downloads the latest `.AppImage` and replaces the current one.

You can accomplish the same thing by deleting your existing `.AppImage` then downloading the latest one from https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/data-science-experience/purchase#purchasing.

**Note**: do not uninstall DSX Desktop through the settings page since it will remove all the docker images you installed (RStudio, Jupyter, Zeppelin). Instead, just remove the `.AppImage`.

**Edit**: I just noticed this in the logs:

```
[2018-02-26 12:07:54:0537] [error] Cannot write to the directory /usr/bin
```

Did you put DSX Desktop inside `/usr/bin`? That would explain why the app can't update itself, since it doesn't have permission to write to that directory.

Comment: Jerry, I tried that.  It didn't work, since the new image won't install if there is a .config directory already existing for DSX.  What I had to do was rename the.config directory to make it look like a fresh install, then do the full install of the new .AppImage, then selectively cut-and-paste the code back into all of my Jupyter networks.  Why bother having a "Upgrade" button at all if it is this complicated?

Comment: Could you elaborate as to how the "new image won't install if there is a .config directory already existing"? I understand that the `~/.config/ibm-dsx-desktop` directory contains all the files and settings, but I don't see how having an existing one would prevent you from installing the application,

Comment: Given that it took 2 months to get a response on this, I have since forgotten all the steps I took to finally get 1.2.3 installed.  It is unfortunate the use of Stack does not provide timely response to problems.

Comment: Hey Tony, I'm sorry it took so long for you to get a response. We're trying to be more active on our help channels (GitHub & StackOverflow), so hopefully this won't happen again. Also, if you don't mind, we prefer to have issues be submitted via our [GitHub](https://github.com/IBMDataScience/DSx-Desktop/issues), since it's easier to track.